# Create a TRIGGER/EVENT in PHP/MS SQL 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to write an Insert on table A which will automatically insert a value into table A after every 24 hours if there's no data for that day. How would I go around writing this? Below is my code. It runs well but doesn't insert anything into the table.

```
Declare @incidentlevel varchar(50)
set @incidentlevel = 'free'

If exists (Select * from TABLE1 where date = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)) AND incidentlevel = '')

BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (incidentlevel) VALUES (@incidentlevel)
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE date = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101))

END;
```

I'm developing this in PHP/MSSQL 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  A description of the problem would help.  I strongly suspect this isn't the best approach to the problem.

Comment: You should be looking into Jobs in SqlServer if you to run it on a schedule.

Comment: @dan1111, thanks for the reply. 

So, I have a table and I want to insert the test '`free`' into the column called '`incidentlevel`' after every 24 hrs provided that column is empty for that specific date. I was trying to use Stored Procedures.

Comment: @mxix thanks for your contribution. I'll look into that.

Comment: @user, I think that is better handled at the data display level.  Your table of incidents should only store incidents, and then when you display that you can handle empty dates in whatever way makes most sense.  Having it in the table doesn't really get you anything, and it creates complexity and a potential maintenance problem.

Comment: Thanks @dan1111 for your help, but I am the more confused by your response. I am trying to use the Jobs in GUI mode now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it with Job using SQL Server Agent. Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction.